# CocoaPods: Mix Objective-C and Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm working on a custom CocoaPod to be deployed privately. Most of the code in this pod is existing code written in Objective-C.

All of the Objective-C code is perfectly accessible from both Objective-C and Swift in implementing projects, but I don't seem to be able to access any of the Swift code from either language in the implementing projects. I would like to be able to use and update the existing Objective-C code, but use Swift for anything new and for Swift specific features.

How can I use Swift code from a primarily Objective-C CocoaPod in Swift files in my implementing project?

My CocoaPod is called XibisFrameworkPod, and I've tried using the following import statements in my implementing project Swift files:

```
import XibisFrameworkPod
import XibisFrameworkPod.Swift
```

Here's my redacted podspec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'XibisFrameworkPod'
  s.version          = '0.1.0'
  # s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/<TWITTER_USERNAME>'

  s.ios.deployment_target = '7.0'

  s.source_files = 'XibisFrameworkPod/Classes/**/*'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was just missing the `public` modifier on the class/function declarations:

```
public class SomeClass : NSObject
```